# Can't get union to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather long query, and I got it to work, kind of. I can;t get the two unions to work since both have different FROM clauses (I THINK)
I think it would be best to post most of it because it is very convoluted. sorry if it takes up so much space.

```
  SELECT
     ISNULL(#tempBacklog.Division, #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.Division) AS 'Division',
      'NONE' as 'Division ID',
      'NONE' as 'NAME',
      'NONE' AS 'Sales Engineer',
      0.00 As 'Current MTD SALES',
      0.00 As 'Last Year MTD SALES',
      0.00 as 'Projected MTD Sales',
    ISNULL(Backlog, 0) AS 'Backlog',
    ISNULL([Complete Not Invoiced], 0) AS 'Completed Not Invoiced',
    ISNULL(#tempBacklog.CUSTACCOUNT, #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.CUSTACCOUNT) AS 'accountnum'
FROM
    --#tempSales FULL OUTER JOIN
    #tempBacklog FULL OUTER JOIN
    #tempCompleteNotInvoiced ON #tempBacklog.ITEMGROUPID = #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.ITEMGROUPID 
    AND #tempBacklog.Division = #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.Division 
    AND #tempBacklog.[Ledger Account] = #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.[Ledger Account] 
    AND #tempBacklog.CUSTACCOUNT = #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.CUSTACCOUNT

union all   
 --Temp table for JE voucher entries , because of dupilacte entries in Custinvoice and CustInoviceJour table
      select Division,
      [Division ID],
      [NAME],
      CASE WHEN IsNull([Sales Engineer],'')='' Then Division+'-UnKnown' ELSE [Sales Engineer] END AS 'Sales Engineer',
      (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([1])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([2])      
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([3])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([4])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([5])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([6])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([7])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([8])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([9])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([10])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([11])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([12])
        END) As 'Current MTD SALES',
      (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([L1])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([L2])      
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([L3])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([L4])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([L5])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([L6])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([L7])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([L8])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([L9])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([L10])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([L11])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([L12])
        END) As 'Last Year MTD SALES',
      (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([YTD1])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([YTD2])      
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([YTD3])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([YTD4])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([YTD5])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([YTD6])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([YTD7])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([YTD8])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([YTD9])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([YTD10])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([YTD11])
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([YTD12])
         END) as 'Projected MTD Sales',

      SUM(Backlog) AS 'Backlog',
    SUM([Completed Not Invoiced]) AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
    ,accountnum
      from
      (   

      select          
                  IsNULL([DESCRIPTION],'None') as Division,
                  LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',      
                  'NONE' as 'NAME',
                  'NONE' as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
                  'NONE' AS 'Industry',
                  'NONE' as 'Street',
                  'NONE' as 'City',
                  'NONE' as 'State',
                  'NONE' as 'ZipCode',
                  '' as 'Sales Engineer',--IsNULL([DESCRIPTION],'None')+'-UnKnown' AS 'Sales Engineer',
                  'NONE' as 'SalesGroup',
                  '' as 'SALESMANID',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST]  ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                  -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',
                  0.00 as 'Projection',    
                  0.00 AS 'YTD Projection',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD1',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD2',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD3',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD4',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD5',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD6',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD7',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD8',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD9',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD10',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD11',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD12',
                  0.00 as 'Year Goal',
                  '' as 'PROJECTION COMMENT'  
                  ,0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                  0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'      
            from dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
            inner Join dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ    on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate and AccountType = '0'
            and LJ.ACCOUNTNUM = LT.ACCOUNTNUM and LT.DIMENSION2_=LJ.DIMENSION2_
            and LT.AMOUNTMST = (CASE WHEN AMOUNTCURDEBIT != 0 then AMOUNTCURDEBIT else -1*AMOUNTCURCREDIT END)
            Inner JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS ON NUM = LT.DIMENSION2_
            Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD on LD.ACCOUNTNUM = LJ.ACCOUNTNUM and LD.ACCOUNTNUM = LT.ACCOUNTNUM
            --inner join #tempTotals on LJ.accountnum = #temptotals.[Ledger Account]
            where (@reportType = 'Forecasting' and LJ.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' and  LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' and LJ.DocumentNum = ''
            and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0  
            AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension))
            or 
            (@reportType = 'Financial'  and LJ.DocumentNum = ''
            and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10'
            and LJ.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
            and  LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'  
            AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension))
            group by
            [DESCRIPTION],LT.[DIMENSION2_]  
UNION ALL 

select   
            IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.[DESCRIPTION], ''), d1.[DESCRIPTION]),'None') as Division,
            IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM, ''), d1.NUM),'None') as 'Division ID',         
            cu.[NAME] as 'NAME',
            cu.[ACCOUNTNUM] as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
            BUSINESSSECTORID AS 'Industry',
            cu.[STREET] as 'Street',
            cu.[CITY] as 'City',
            cu.[STATE] as 'State',
            cu.[ZIPCODE] as 'ZipCode',
            [Sales Engineer] as 'Sales Engineer',--IsNULL([DESCRIPTION],'None')+'-UnKnown' AS 'Sales Engineer',
            cu.[SalesGroup] as 'SalesGroup',
            IsNull(tes.SALESMANID,'') as 'SALESMANID',
            SUM([YTD Sales]) as 'YTD Sales',SUM([1]) as '1',SUM([2]) as '2',SUM([3]) as '3',SUM([4]) as '4',SUM([5]) as '5'
            ,SUM([6]) as '6',SUM([7]) as '7',SUM([8]) as '8',SUM([9]) as '9',SUM([10]) as '10',SUM([11]) as '11',SUM([12]) as '12',
            SUM([Last YTD Sales]) as 'Last YTD Sales',SUM([Last Year Sales]) as 'Last Year Sales',
            SUM([L1]) as 'L1',SUM([L2]) as 'L2',SUM([L3]) as 'L3',SUM([L4]) as 'L4',SUM([L5]) as 'L5'
            ,SUM([L6]) as 'L6',SUM([L7]) as 'L7',SUM([L8]) as 'L8',SUM([L9]) as 'L9',SUM([L10]) as 'L10',
            SUM([L11]) as 'L11',SUM([L12]) as 'L12',
            IsNULL(Projection,0.00) as 'Projection',                  
            [YTD Projection] as 'YTD Projection',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@1YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@1YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
       and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD1',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@2YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@2YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD2',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@3YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@3YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD3',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@4YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@4YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD4',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@5YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@5YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD5',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@6YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@6YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD6',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@7YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@7YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD7',
            ISNULL((Select  Top(1)[YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@8YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@8YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD8',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@9YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@9YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD9',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@10YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@10YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD10',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@11YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@11YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD11',
            ISNULL((Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] from #tempSalesTargetMW where STARTDATE>=@12YTDStart and ENDDATE<=@12YTDEnd and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
            and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD12',
                 [Year Goal] as 'Year Goal',[PROJECTION COMMENT],                  
      0.00 AS 'Backlog',
    0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
      from [CUSTTABLE] cu         
            Left JOIN
            (
               select    
                  LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',
                  LJ.ACCOUNTNUM as 'ACCOUNTNUM',    
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',                 
                        LT.[TRANSDATE]
                        ,0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                  0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
                  from
                  dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
                  inner JOIN dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate and AccountType in ('1')            
                  Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD on LD.ACCOUNTNUM = LT.ACCOUNTNUM

                  where
                  (LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400')
                  AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%' 
                  and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) and @reportType='Forecasting'
                  or
                  (LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%'
                  AND LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
                  AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) and @reportType='Financial')
                  group by LJ.ACCOUNTNUM,LT.[DIMENSION2_],LT.[TRANSDATE]

                  union all

             select    
                  LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',
                  LJ.ACCOUNTNUM as 'ACCOUNTNUM',    
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                        -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',                 

                        LT.[TRANSDATE]
                        ,0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                  0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'

                  from
                  dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
                  inner JOIN dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate and AccountType in ('1')            
                  Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD on LD.ACCOUNTNUM = LT.ACCOUNTNUM

                  where
                  (LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400')
                  AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 and @reportType = 'Forecasting'
                  AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension)
                  or
                  (LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' and @reportType = 'Financial'
                  AND LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'
                  AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension))
                  group by LJ.ACCOUNTNUM,LT.[DIMENSION2_],LT.[TRANSDATE]

      ) as Cus  on (cu.ACCOUNTNUM = Cus.ACCOUNTNUM)
            Inner JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS d1 ON NUM = cu.[dimension2_]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS d2 ON d2.NUM = Cus.[Division ID]       
            Left JOIN #tempSalesTarget te on cu.ACCOUNTNUM=te.CUSTACCOUNT
            and te.Division=Cus.[Division ID]
            and cu.SALESGROUP=te.SALESUNITID
            left JOIN #tempSalesEngineers tes ON cu.SALESGROUP=tes.SALESUNITID  and (te.SALESMANID = tes.SALESMANID or te.SalesManID IS NULL)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempCustIndustry ON cu.ACCOUNTNUM = #tempCustIndustry.ACCOUNTNUM

            where IsNull(tes.SALESMANID,'') IN (@SalesEngineer)
            AND cu.[dimension2_] in (@dimension)

            GROUP BY
                  d1.[DESCRIPTION],
                  d2.[DESCRIPTION],
                  d1.NUM,
                  d2.NUM,
                  cu.[NAME],
                  cu.[ACCOUNTNUM],
                  BUSINESSSECTORID,
                  cu.[STREET],
                  cu.[CITY],
                  cu.[STATE],
                  cu.[ZIPCODE],
                  cu.[SalesGroup],
                  [Sales Engineer],
                  tes.SALESMANID,
                  [Projection],
                  [Year Goal],
                  [YTD Projection],           
                  [PROJECTION COMMENT],
                  backlog
```

I am getting two different results for each entry:
[image]

How can I get the rows to match up? the fields for the first query are invalid in the second query

Comment: What's the result you're trying to get?

Comment: The rows (say 5 and 6 in the screen shot) to show values in each column, but in one row. The values for each are correct when they have one, but they are split into two rows (again, i'd like to merge the values in rows 5 & 6 where they have values). I can't figure out how to get the column values into the first query, so i'm replacing them with 'none' and 0.00

Comment: What is your logical key? i.e. what combination of fields here do you want to uniquely identify a row? A union gives you a distinct row for each unique combination of every single column you select, and as you can see, each row in your result has some value different from each other row. You probably want to use a group by (if you want to perform aggregation to combine rows) or a row_number (if you want to pick one row to keep and throw away the others based on some criteria).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it appears your columns dont match... your first query has a column

```
 ISNULL(#tempBacklog.CUSTACCOUNT, #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.CUSTACCOUNT) AS 'accountnum'
```

but there is no corresponding (last column in the second query).  A union needs to be same columns, data types and order.  I think it was just an oversight.  For grins, even if in the second query you add

```
'test' as 'accountnum'
```

just to confirm, see what happens / if it goes through.

ADDITIONALLY, the last column of your second query looks cut short via...

SUM([Completed Not Invoiced]) AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
) as Cus  on (cu.ACCOUNTNUM = Cus.ACCOUNTNUM)

As menstioned, no 'accountnum' column to match the first query, but also not seeing a "FROM" clause and it's initial table before the JOIN.  Again. maybe I'm missing something, but the formatting of the query is not quite there.

I have reformatted the query some for readability from your original.  I changed some of the long #temp aliases to abbreviated for readability purposes.

```
SELECT
        ISNULL(tBL.Division, #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.Division) AS 'Division',
        'NONE' as 'Division ID',
        'NONE' as 'NAME',
        'NONE' AS 'Sales Engineer',
        0.00 As 'Current MTD SALES',
        0.00 As 'Last Year MTD SALES',
        0.00 as 'Projected MTD Sales',
        ISNULL(Backlog, 0) AS 'Backlog',
        ISNULL([Complete Not Invoiced], 0) AS 'Completed Not Invoiced',
        ISNULL(tBL.CUSTACCOUNT, #tempCompleteNotInvoiced.CUSTACCOUNT) AS 'accountnum'
    FROM
         #tempBacklog tBL
             FULL OUTER JOIN #tempCompleteNotInvoiced 
                 ON tBL.ITEMGROUPID = tCNI.ITEMGROUPID 
     AND tBL.Division = tCNI.Division 
     AND tBL.[Ledger Account] = tCNI.[Ledger Account] 
     AND tBL.CUSTACCOUNT = tCNI.CUSTACCOUNT

union all   
select 
        Division,
        [Division ID],
        [NAME],
        CASE WHEN IsNull([Sales Engineer],'')='' 
              Then Division+'-UnKnown' 
              ELSE [Sales Engineer] END AS 'Sales Engineer',

        (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([1])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([2])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([3])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([4])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([5])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([6])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([7])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([8])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([9])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([10])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([11])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([12])
                END) As 'Current MTD SALES',
        (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([L1])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([L2])        
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([L3])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([L4])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([L5])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([L6])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([L7])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([L8])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([L9])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([L10])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([L11])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([L12])
                END) As 'Last Year MTD SALES',
        (case WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 then SUM([YTD1])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 then SUM([YTD2])      
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN SUM([YTD3])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN SUM([YTD4])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN SUM([YTD5])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN SUM([YTD6])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN SUM([YTD7])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN SUM([YTD8])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN SUM([YTD9])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN SUM([YTD10])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN SUM([YTD11])
                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN SUM([YTD12])
                END) as 'Projected MTD Sales',
        SUM(Backlog) AS 'Backlog',
        SUM([Completed Not Invoiced]) AS 'Completed Not Invoiced',
        accountnum
    from
        ( select
                  IsNULL([DESCRIPTION],'None') as Division,
                  LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',        
                  'NONE' as 'NAME',
                  'NONE' as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
                  'NONE' AS 'Industry',
                  'NONE' as 'Street',
                  'NONE' as 'City',
                  'NONE' as 'State',
                  'NONE' as 'ZipCode',
                  '' as 'Sales Engineer',
                  'NONE' as 'SalesGroup',
                  '' as 'SALESMANID',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST]  ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                  -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',
                  0.00 as 'Projection',  
                  0.00 AS 'YTD Projection',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD1',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD2',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD3',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD4',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD5',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD6',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD7',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD8',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD9',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD10',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD11',
                  0.00 AS 'YTD12',
                  0.00 as 'Year Goal',
                  '' as 'PROJECTION COMMENT',
                  0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                  0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
              from 
                  dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
                      inner Join dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ     
                            on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher 
                          and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate 
                          and AccountType = '0'
                          and LT.ACCOUNTNUM = LJ.ACCOUNTNUM 
                          and LT.DIMENSION2_ = LJ.DIMENSION2_
                          and LT.AMOUNTMST = (CASE WHEN AMOUNTCURDEBIT != 0 
                                                            then AMOUNTCURDEBIT 
                                                            else -1 * AMOUNTCURCREDIT END)
                      Inner JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS 
                          ON LT.DIMENSION2_ = NUM
                      Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD 
                            ON LT.ACCOUNTNUM = LD.ACCOUNTNUM
                          AND LJ.ACCOUNTNUM = LD.ACCOUNTNUM  
              where 
                        (   @reportType = 'Forecasting' 
                        and LJ.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
                        and LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
                        and LJ.DocumentNum = ''
                        and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' 
                        and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0  
                        AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension))
                  OR
                        (   @reportType = 'Financial'  
                        and LJ.DocumentNum = ''
                        and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10'
                        and LJ.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
                        and LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'  
                        AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension))
              group by
                    [DESCRIPTION],
                    LT.[DIMENSION2_]  

          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 
                  IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.[DESCRIPTION], ''), d1.[DESCRIPTION]),'None') as Division,
                  IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM, ''), d1.NUM),'None') as 'Division ID',           
                  cu.[NAME] as 'NAME',
                  cu.[ACCOUNTNUM] as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
                  BUSINESSSECTORID AS 'Industry',
                  cu.[STREET] as 'Street',
                  cu.[CITY] as 'City',
                  cu.[STATE] as 'State',
                  cu.[ZIPCODE] as 'ZipCode',
                  [Sales Engineer] as 'Sales Engineer',
                  cu.[SalesGroup] as 'SalesGroup',
                  IsNull(tes.SALESMANID,'') as 'SALESMANID',
                  SUM([YTD Sales]) as 'YTD Sales',
                  SUM([1]) as '1',
                  SUM([2]) as '2',
                  SUM([3]) as '3',
                  SUM([4]) as '4',
                  SUM([5]) as '5',
                  SUM([6]) as '6',
                  SUM([7]) as '7',
                  SUM([8]) as '8',
                  SUM([9]) as '9',
                  SUM([10]) as '10',
                  SUM([11]) as '11',
                  SUM([12]) as '12',
                  SUM([Last YTD Sales]) as 'Last YTD Sales',
                  SUM([Last Year Sales]) as 'Last Year Sales',
                  SUM([L1]) as 'L1',
                  SUM([L2]) as 'L2',
                  SUM([L3]) as 'L3',
                  SUM([L4]) as 'L4',
                  SUM([L5]) as 'L5',
                  SUM([L6]) as 'L6',
                  SUM([L7]) as 'L7',
                  SUM([L8]) as 'L8',
                  SUM([L9]) as 'L9',
                  SUM([L10]) as 'L10',
                  SUM([L11]) as 'L11',
                  SUM([L12]) as 'L12',
                  IsNULL(Projection,0.00) as 'Projection',
                  [YTD Projection] as 'YTD Projection',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @1YTDStart 
                                      and ENDDATE <= @1YTDEnd 
                                      and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                      and Division = IsNULL( ISNULL( NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null ) 
                                      and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup] ), 0) AS 'YTD1',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE> = @2YTDStart 
                                      and ENDDATE <= @2YTDEnd 
                                      and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                      and Division = IsNULL( ISNULL( NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM), null ) 
                                      and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD2',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @3YTDStart 
                                      and ENDDATE <= @3YTDEnd 
                                      and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                      and Division = IsNULL( ISNULL( NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                      and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD3',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @4YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @4YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL( ISNULL( NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD4',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @5YTDStart 
                                      and ENDDATE <= @5YTDEnd 
                                      and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                      and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                      and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD5',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @6YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @6YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD6',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @7YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @7YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD7',
                  ISNULL( ( Select  Top(1)[YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @8YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @8YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD8',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @9YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @9YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD9',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @10YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @10YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD10',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @11YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @11YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD11',
                  ISNULL( ( Select Top(1) [YTD Projection] 
                                    from #tempSalesTargetMW 
                                    where STARTDATE >= @12YTDStart 
                                    and ENDDATE <= @12YTDEnd 
                                    and CUSTACCOUNT = cu.[ACCOUNTNUM]
                                    and Division = IsNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(d2.NUM,null), d1.NUM),null) 
                                    and SalesUnitId = cu.[SalesGroup]),0) AS 'YTD12',
                  [Year Goal] as 'Year Goal',
                  [PROJECTION COMMENT],
                  0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                  0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
              from 
                  [CUSTTABLE] cu
                      Left JOIN ( select
                                              LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',
                                              LJ.ACCOUNTNUM as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                                              -1 * SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',                   
                                              LT.[TRANSDATE],
                                              0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                                              0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
                                          from
                                              dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
                                                  inner JOIN dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ 
                                                        on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher 
                                                      and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate 
                                                      and AccountType in ('1')
                                                      Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD 
                                                          on LT.ACCOUNTNUM = LD.ACCOUNTNUM
                                          where
                                                    LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'
                                              AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
                                              and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' 
                                              and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%' 
                                              and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 
                                              AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) 
                                              and @reportType='Forecasting'
                                              or
                                                  ( LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
                                                  and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' 
                                                  and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%'
                                                  AND LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
                                                  AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) 
                                                  and @reportType='Financial')
                                          group by 
                                              LJ.ACCOUNTNUM,
                                              LT.[DIMENSION2_],
                                              LT.[TRANSDATE]

                                      union all
                                      select     
                                              LT.[DIMENSION2_] AS 'Division ID',
                                              LJ.ACCOUNTNUM as 'ACCOUNTNUM',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @YTD THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD Sales',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS '2',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @3Start AND @3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @4Start AND @4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @5Start AND @5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @6Start AND @6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @7Start AND @7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @8Start AND @8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @9Start AND @9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '9',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @10Start AND @10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @11Start AND @11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '11',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @12Start AND @12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS '12',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYTD_Start AND @LYTD_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last YTD Sales',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @LYS_End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year Sales',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L1Start AND @L1End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L1',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L2Start AND @L2End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END)  AS 'L2',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L3Start AND @L3End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L3',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L4Start AND @L4End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L4',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L5Start AND @L5End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L5',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L6Start AND @L6End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L6',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L7Start AND @L7End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L7',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L8Start AND @L8End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L8',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L9Start AND @L9End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L9',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L10Start AND @L10End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L10',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L11Start AND @L11End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L11',
                                              -1*SUM(CASE WHEN LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @L12Start AND @L12End THEN LT.[AMOUNTMST] ELSE 0 END) AS 'L12',                     
                                              LT.[TRANSDATE],
                                              0.00 AS 'Backlog',
                                              0.00 AS 'Completed Not Invoiced'
                                          from
                                              dbo.[LedgerTrans] LT
                                                  inner JOIN dbo.[LedgerJournalTrans] LJ 
                                                        on LT.Voucher = LJ.Voucher 
                                                      and LT.TransDate = LJ.TransDate 
                                                      and AccountType in ('1')
                                                  Inner Join dbo.LedgerTable LD 
                                                      on LT.ACCOUNTNUM = LD.ACCOUNTNUM
                                          where
                                                    LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'
                                              AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
                                              and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' 
                                              and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 
                                              and @reportType = 'Forecasting'
                                              AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension)
                                              OR  
                                                  ( LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
                                                  and LT.[DIMENSION2_] != '10' 
                                                  and @reportType = 'Financial'
                                                  AND LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'
                                                  AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) )
                                          group by 
                                              LJ.ACCOUNTNUM,
                                              LT.[DIMENSION2_],
                                              LT.[TRANSDATE] ) as Cus  
                      on cu.ACCOUNTNUM = Cus.ACCOUNTNUM
                  Inner JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS d1 
                      ON cu.[dimension2_] = NUM
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DIMENSIONS 
                          d2 ON Cus.[Division ID] = d2.NUM
                  Left JOIN #tempSalesTarget te 
                      on cu.ACCOUNTNUM = te.CUSTACCOUNT
                     and te.Division = Cus.[Division ID]
                     and cu.SALESGROUP = te.SALESUNITID
                  left JOIN #tempSalesEngineers tes 
                      ON cu.SALESGROUP = tes.SALESUNITID  
                     and (te.SALESMANID = tes.SALESMANID or te.SalesManID IS NULL)
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempCustIndustry 
                      ON cu.ACCOUNTNUM = #tempCustIndustry.ACCOUNTNUM

              where 
                        IsNull(tes.SALESMANID,'') IN (@SalesEngineer)
                  AND cu.[dimension2_] in (@dimension)
              GROUP BY
                  d1.[DESCRIPTION],
                  d2.[DESCRIPTION],
                  d1.NUM,
                  d2.NUM,
                  cu.[NAME],
                  cu.[ACCOUNTNUM],
                  BUSINESSSECTORID,
                  cu.[STREET],
                  cu.[CITY],
                  cu.[STATE],
                  cu.[ZIPCODE],
                  cu.[SalesGroup],
                  [Sales Engineer],
                  tes.SALESMANID,
                  [Projection],
                  [Year Goal],
                  [YTD Projection],           
                  [PROJECTION COMMENT],
                  backlog
```

Now, in the lower queries where you are doing the "cu" and "cus" select/unions, you have some where clauses like...

```
where
       ( LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400')
   AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
   and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' 
   and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%' 
   and LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 
   AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) 
   and @reportType='Forecasting'

   or
      (   LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
      and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' 
      and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%'
      AND LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400' 
      AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) 
      and @reportType='Financial' )
```

Is that what you expected (for both instances), or should it have been

```
  where 
      ( first set of criteria )
      OR
      ( second set of criteria )
```

But could be simplified down to...

```
where
       LT.ACCOUNTNUM between '400100' and '409400'
   AND LT.[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN @LYS_Start AND @12End 
   and LT.[DIMENSION2_] = '10' 
   and LT.Voucher Not Like 'JE%' 
   AND LT.[DIMENSION2_] in (@dimension) 
   and (  (    LD.KTI_OASALESCOMM = 0 
            and @reportType='Forecasting' )
        or
           @reportType='Financial' 
       )
```

Comment: I've updated the query to show more of whats going on with the from clause

Comment: @rigamonk, reformatted readability again, but have question at bottom regarding WHERE clause in lower queries.  Also, where are your @ variables declared

Comment: I cant fit the variables in the provided text, it exceeds the limits.I posted the variables @ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/315f694c-ade9-4ddf-af5f-c14665ff5ed7/cant-get-union-to-work?forum=transactsql